# Why can -respondsToSelector: instance method be used on class name or class object?

Tags: objective-c, class, class-method, instance-methods, respondstoselector

In Programming in Objective C, 4e, Chapter 9, Program 9.3:

```
#import "Square.h"
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
   @autoreleasepool {
      Square *mySquare = [[Square alloc] init];
      ...
      // respondsTo:
      if ( [mySquare respondsToSelector: @selector (setSide:)] == YES )
         NSLog (@"mySquare responds to setSide: method");
      ...
      if ( [Square respondsToSelector: @selector (alloc)] == YES )
         NSLog (@"Square class responds to alloc method");
      ...
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Q1:

Since `-respondsToSelector:` is an instance method, not a class method, why would it be possible to use it on `Square` class directly?

Q2:

The book says you can use `Square` here instead of `[Square class]`. Is it only a exceptional shortcut, or is there any mechanism behind this?

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. The short answer is because when it boils down to it, they're all selectors. 2. Square (uppercase) is already a class, the `class` method  literally returns the same object.

Comment: Q2: `Square` evaluates to the meta class of Square, which is an object that represents the Square class. It's an object instance, so you can message it. Sending `+class` to a meta class object, returns itself.

Comment: actually, my above comment answers both your questions :)

Comment: @CodaFi : Thanks for quick reply! But, aren't instance methods (such as `-respondsToSelector:` ) supposed to be used on instance objects only?

Comment: Well, you have to understand what a selector is. no matter if it's a class or instance method, all selectors are of type SEL, which is one of the arguments the method takes.   it just checks if the CLASS you provide responds to it.  Class methods can be called inside instance methods anyhow, so the point is moot.

Comment: @nielsbot : So basically, `Square` is a class object and an instance object at the same time? In my previous understanding, class objects and instances are totally different.

Comment: To answer your question to neilsbot, he was only discussing the redundancy of calling -class on a Class.

Comment: @PickBoy: At runtime, `Square` evaluates to an instance object that stands for the `Square` class. So it's an instance representing the class `Square`. Make sense? It's a little "meta"

Comment: @hotpaw's answer agrees with mine

Comment: @nielsbot Yeah, after reading all the posts here, it seems that the underlying implementation of instance/class are related, which explains the strange behavior (to me at least...) in this case. Thanks so much guys!

Comment: @nielsbot: "`Square` evaluates to the meta class of Square" What? No. `Square` evaluates to the Square class object, not its metaclass

Comment: you are right--Class is itself an object. the class of a class is its metaclass

Answer (score 4):

From *The Objective-C Programming Language*, [Objects, class, and Messaging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html),

> All objects, classes and instances alike, need an interface to the
>   runtime system. Both class objects and instances should be able to
>   introspect about their abilities and to report their place in the
>   inheritance hierarchy. It’s the province of the NSObject class to
>   provide this interface.
>
> So that NSObject methods don’t have to be implemented twice—once to
>   provide a runtime interface for instances and again to duplicate that
>   interface for class objects—**class objects are given special dispensation to perform instance methods defined in the root class**.
>   When a class object receives a message that it can’t respond to with a
>   class method, the runtime system determines whether there’s a root
>   instance method that can respond. The **only** instance methods that a
>   class object can perform are those **defined in the root class**, and **only if there’s no class method that can do the job**.

In this case, `NSObject` is the root class. As `NSObject` instances all comply with `NSObject protocol`, where `-respondsToSelector:` is defined, most class objects should be able to perform `-respondsToSelector:`.

Answer (score 4):

Q1:

The simple answer is that, in addition to class methods, you can call any instances method of the root class (whatever the root class of your class is; in this case, `NSObject`) on a class object.

The more complicated answer is that class objects are instances of metaclasses. Whereas instance methods are methods on an instance, which are defined in the class; class methods are methods on the class object, which are defined in the metaclass. Each class has its own metaclass. The inheritance of metaclasses follows that of their classes; i.e. `NSString`'s metaclass inherits from `NSObject`'s metaclass. Ultimately, the root class's metaclass inherits from the root class; i.e. `NSObject`'s metaclass inherits from `NSObject`. That is why all of NSObject's instance methods are available to class objects.

Q2:

`[Square class]` calls the class method `+class` (this is unrelated to `-class`). `+class` is essentially an identity method that simply returns the thing called on it (just like `-self`); i.e. if `foo` is a pointer to a class object, then `[foo class]` is the same as `foo`.

So `+class` seems pretty useless; why do we use it? That is because in the grammar of the Objective-C language, a class name is not a valid expression (unlike Smalltalk). So you cannot say `id bar = Square;`; that would not compile. As a special case in the grammar, a class name is allowed in place of the receiver in a message call expression, and the message is sent to the class object; i.e. `[Square something]`. So if you want to use the class object in any other expression context, we do this in a roundabout way by calling an identity method like `+class`; i.e. `[Square class]` is an expression that can be used in any expression context (`[Square self]` would also work, but we use `[Square class]` by convention, which is unfortunate, since it is confused with `-class`); we would have liked to just use `Square`, but can't due to the language.

In your case, it is already the receiver in a message call expression, so it is unnecessary to do `[Square class]`; `Square` already works there.

Answer (score 0):

//Q1:

Since -respondsToSelector: is an instance method, not a class method, why would it be possible to use it on Square class directly?//

You seem to have this notion that class methods cannot be called from instance methods (and vice versa).  On the contrary, it would seem to be the intent of the method -respondsToSelector to do so, most likely by getting the class of the sender with the -class method, then querying if the class responds to the selector and returning YES or NO.  In a more localized example, consider the following:

```
-(void)someInstanceMethod{
     [MyCurrentClass doClassMethod]; //basic equivalent of [self doClassMethid];
}
```

Is perfectly valid in Objective-C, provided MyCurrentClass is all alloc'd and init'ed.

//Q2:

The book says you can use Square here instead of [Square class]. Is it only a exceptional shortcut, or is there any mechanism behind this?//

It is completely redundant to send -class to a Class!  It makes little sense, and is just extra unnecessary code.  -class just queries for the reciever's class, no matter if it is an instance or Class object.

Comment: it should be +class on Q2, otherwise the call would not work.

Comment: I'll also note that class methods ALSO belong to instances, but do not take precedence.

Comment: Your Q1 completely missed the question, which is why you can call `respondsToSelector:` on a class object.

Answer (score 0):

The Objective C run-time currently implements a class as an instance object of some other class.  Thus a class will response to certain instance methods.

Answer (score -1):

The real implementation, straight out of NSObject.m is as such:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
        PF_HELLO("")
        return class_respondsToSelector( isa, aSelector );
}
```

Now, I have no idea why that `PF_HELLO("")` is there, but as you can see, it's literally ASKING the CLASS in the RUNTIME "Hey, do you have a method for this isa [instance] called aSelector?"

And, in Objective-C, class methods ALSO belong to instances, but, however, take lower precedence (the instance method of the same name as the class method is called before the class method).

Another aspect of Objective-C's Dynamic Typing is that the `id` type is in fact declared as follows:

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

So your instance object is in fact, a Class pointer. This means your -respondsToSelector messages go to the Class of the instance type as well. In your case, it means that -respondsToSelector is going to the objc_class FIRST.

Now in a test case, (straight out of libFoundation), my answer would be summed up like this:

```
Test *tst = [Test new];

    fail_unless([tst respondsToSelector:@selector(testInstanceMethod)], "-[Test respondsToSelector:] returned NO for a valid instance method (testInstanceMethod).");
    fail_if([tst respondsToSelector:@selector(testClassMethod)], "-[Test respondsToSelector:] returned YES for a class method (testInstanceMethod).");
    fail_unless([Test respondsToSelector:@selector(testClassMethod)], "+[Test respondsToSelector:] returned NO for a valid class method (testClassMethod).");
    fail_if([Test respondsToSelector:@selector(testInstanceMethod)], "+[Test respondsToSelector:] returned YES for an instance method (testInstanceMethod).");
    fail_unless([tst respondsToSelector:@selector(init)], "-[Test respondsToSelector:] returned NO for an inherited instance method (-[NSObject init].");
    fail_unless([Test respondsToSelector:@selector(alloc)], "+[Test respondsToSelector:] returned NO for an inherited class method (+[NSObject alloc]).");

    [tst release];
```

Comment: I wonder where the NSObject.m codes come from. No idea when Apple open-sourced their Foundation framework.

Comment: Old news, GNUStep and Cocoatron. GNUStep is based on the OpenStep which precedes the Mac OS X Foundation (and comes from the original NextStep Foundation).

Comment: Do you mean that all instance methods can perform on class objects? But @ZhangChn 's answer says that only instance methods defined in root class can perform on class objects. Any idea about this contradiction? Thanks!

Comment: What he explained is what I defined as precedence - objects can perform class methods as well. The converse works as well, which is what I provided, straight from GNUStep source and libFoundation tests.

Comment: "And, in Objective-C, class methods ALSO belong to instances, but, however, take lower precedence" Completely false and wrong. "So your instance object is in fact, a Class pointer." What? That says that the `isa` field of an object is a class pointer, i.e. if you have `id obj;` then `obj->isa` is a class pointer; you can even do `(Class)*obj` which is a class pointer; but `obj` is not a class pointer. "This means your -respondsToSelector messages go to the Class of the instance type as well." Absolutely not.